# How to extract from multiple tables with different structure to one flat file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, ssis

I have following three tables, which can be joined using the common column, key and they have different number of columns.

```
table1 (key, colnA-1, colnA-2, …, colnA-n)
table2 (key, colnB-1, colnB-2, …, colnB-m)
table3 (key, colnC-1, colnC-2, …, colnC-i)
```

I need to combine the three tables and export to a flat file like following

```
colnA-1, colnA-2, A, colnA-3, …, colnA-n
colnA-1, colnA-2, B, colnB-1, colnB-2, …, colnB-m
colnA-1, colnA-2, B, colnB-1, colnB-2, …, colnB-m
colnA-1, colnA-2, B, colnB-1, colnB-2, …, colnB-m
…
colnA-1, colnA-2, C, colnC-1, colnC-2, …, colnC-i
colnA-1, colnA-2, C, colnC-1, colnC-2, …, colnC-i
colnA-1, colnA-2, C, colnC-1, colnC-2, …, colnC-i
…

A means the data in rest of the line are from table1, B means the data in the rest of the line are from table2, etc.
```

My first question is that is it possible to write a query to join the three tables to generate a final table with the structure like above, then I could use SSIS to export the data to a flat file from the final table? My own answer to this is maybe not, since the record from table A has different structure from the record from table B.

Another question is, since I am fairly new to create a SSIS package, my only experience using SSIS is to do import/export in SSMS, can anybody share some idea how to create an SSIS package to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how you're joining the three tables.  I'd need specifics to be more precise.

The basic idea is to go

```
SELECT colnA-1, colnA-2, 'A', …, colnA-n
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT colnB-1, colnB-2, 'B', …, colnB-n
FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT colnC-1, colnC-2, 'C', …, colnC-n
FROM table3
```

If your datatypes are incompatible, you'll need to use `CAST()` statements to make them compatible.

When you're building the package and selecting a data source, choose an OLE DB Source.  In the configuration window, instead of picking a table, choose an SQL command.  Then paste your working query into SSIS.

[image]

Comment: I cannot cast them to the same type. The three tables has different structure, different number of columns and different type of columns.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to extract them to different files and then concatenate them into a single file with an Execute Process Task (calling cmd.exe with a single command or batch file).  The File Connections in SSIS are field-oriented and it does a reasonable amount of data checking, so you'll probably have issues trying to export three files to the same output file.  If you intend to use these files to later import with SSIS, you'll have to use three individual files or normalize your fields between them to use a single file.